# Mongodb Arrayfilter query in golang for update operation

Tags: database, mongodb, go, aggregation-framework

I want to do update operation on mongodb. Mongodb query consist arrayList :
I want to implement endexamfunction which will simply increment attemptCount
My learner document like Learner consist []course , course consist []exam & exam consist attemptcount

Query :

```
db.learner.updateOne(
    {
    "username": "USERNAME",
    },
    {
        $inc : {
            "courses.$[i].exams.$[j].attemptscompleted":1,
        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            {"i.coursename": "COURSENAME"}, 
            {"j.examid": "EXAMID"}
        ]
    }
)
```

In golang I take username,coursename & examid as param.
This is how my golang function looks like:

```
func EndExam(username, coursename, examid string) {
    client, err := connectionHelper.GetMongoClient()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    collection := client.Database(connectionHelper.DB).Collection(connectionHelper.LEARNER)

    res := collection.FindOneAndUpdate(
        context.Background(),
        bson.D{
            {Key: "username", Value: username},
        },
        bson.D{
            {Key: "$inc", Value: bson.D{
                {Key: "courses.$[i].exams.$[j].attemptscompleted", Value: 1},
            }},
        },
        options.FindOneAndUpdate().SetArrayFilters(options.ArrayFilters{
            Filters: []interface{}{bson.D{
                {Key: "i.coursename", Value: coursename},
                {Key: "j.examid", Value: examid},
            }},
        }).SetReturnDocument(1),
    )

    fmt.Println(res)

}
```

I got error: &{{9 Error parsing array filter :: caused by :: Expected a single top-level field name, found 'i' and 'j' [] FailedToParse }  [] }

It looks like I messed with arrayfilter. but I dont know how to use them in such cases. I am either looking for solution Or Better way to look this query in golang

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
options.FindOneAndUpdate().SetArrayFilters(options.ArrayFilters{
            Filters: []interface{}{
            bson.D{
                {Key: "i.coursename", Value: coursename},
            },
            bson.D{
                {Key: "j.examid", Value: examid},
            },
        })
```

bson.D - is document representation. In your case it will be converted as :

```
{"i.coursename": "COURSNAME", "j.examid": "EXAMID"}
```